# gnu FORTRAN unformatted file record markers stored as 64-bit width?

Tags: file, fortran, gnu

I have a legacy code and some unformatted data files that it reads, and it worked with gnu-4.1.2. I don't have access to the method that originally generated these data files. When I compile this code with a newer gnu compiler (gnu-4.7.2) and attempt to load the old data files on a different computer, it is having difficulty reading them. I start by opening the file and reading in the first record which consists of three 32-bit integers:

```
open(unit, file='data.bin', form='unformatted', status='old')
read(unit) x,y,z
```

I am expecting these three integers here to describe x,y,z spans so that next it can load a 3D matrix of `float` values with those same dimensions. However, instead it's loading a `0` for the first value, then the next two are offset.

Expecting:

```
x=26, y=127, z=97    (1A, 7F, 61 in hex)
```

Loaded:

```
x=0, y=26, z=127     (0, 1A, 7F in hex)
```

When I checked the data file in a hex editor, I think I figured out what was happening.

[image: hex editor]

The first record marker in this case has a value of `12` (`0C` in hex) since it's reading three integers at `4` bytes each. This marker is stored both *before* and *after* the record. However, I notice that the 32bits immediately after each record marker is `00000000`. So either the record markers are treated as 64bit integers (little-Endian) or there is a 32-bit zero padding after each record marker. Either way, the code generated with the new compiler is reading the record markers as 32-bit integers and not expecting any padding. This effectively intrudes/corrupts the data being read in.

Is there an easy way to fix this non-portable issue? The old and new hardware are 64 bit architecture and so is the executable I compiled. If I try to use the older compiler version again will it solve the problem, or is it hardware dependent? I'd prefer to use the newer compilers because they are more efficient, and I really don't want to edit the source code to open all the files as `access='stream'` and manually read in a trailing `0` integer after each record marker, both before and after each record.

P.S. I could probably write a C++ code to alter the data files and remove these zero paddings if there is no easier alternative.

Comment: *Is there an easy way to fix this non-portable issue?* No.  That's a feature of most binary file reading and writing, certainly with Fortran, where the form and layout of a binary file has never been standardised.  You seem to be doing what most of us do when faced with the same problem, opening a hex editor, doing some exploratory reading, scratching your head, contemplating modifying the file to another binary format which will be incompatible with the next program to read the file, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the -frecord-marker= option in the gfortran manual. With -frecord-marker=8 you can read the old style unformatted sequential files produced by older versions of gfortran.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. "Specify the length of record markers for unformatted files. Valid values for length are 4 and 8. Default is 4. This is different from previous versions of gfortran, which specified a default record marker length of 8 on most systems. If you want to read or write files compatible with earlier versions of gfortran, use -frecord-marker=8."

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how Fortran doesn't have a standardization on this, I opted to convert the data files to a new format that uses 32-bit wide record lengths instead of 64-bit wide. In case anyone needs to do this in the future I've included some Visual C++ code here that worked for me and should be easily modifiable to C or another language. I have also uploaded a [Windows executable (fortrec.zip) here](https://sites.google.com/site/master1hd/software).

```
CFile OldFortFile, OutFile; 
const int BUFLEN = 1024*20;
char pbuf[BUFLEN];
int i, iIn, iRecLen, iRecLen2, iLen, iRead, iError = 0;

CString strInDir = "C:\folder\";
CString strIn = "file.dat";
CString strOutDir = "C:\folder\fortnew\"
system("mkdir \"" + strOutDir + "\""); //create a subdir to hold the output files
strIn = strInDir + strIn;
strOut = strOutDir + strIn;
if(OldFortFile.Open(strIn,CFile::modeRead|CFile::typeBinary)) {
    if(OutFile.Open(strOut,CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite|CFile::typeBinary)) {
        while(true) {
            iRead = OldFortFile.Read(&iRecLen, sizeof(iRecLen)); //Read the record's raw data
            if (iRead < sizeof(iRecLen)) //end of file reached
                break;
            OutFile.Write(&iRecLen, sizeof(iRecLen));//Write the record's raw data
            OldFortFile.Read(&iIn, sizeof(iIn));
            if (iIn != 0) {//this is the padding we need to ignore, ensure it's always zero
                //Padding not found
                iError++;
                break;
            }
            i = iRecLen;
            while (i > 0) {
                iLen = (i > BUFLEN) ? BUFLEN : i;
                OldFortFile.Read(&pbuf[0], iLen);
                OutFile.Write(&pbuf[0], iLen);
                i -= iLen;
            }
            if (i != 0) { //Buffer length mismatch  
                iError++;
                break;
            }
            OldFortFile.Read(&iRecLen2, sizeof(iRecLen2));
            if (iRecLen != iRecLen2) {//ensure we have reached the end of the record proeprly
                //Record length mismatch
                iError++;
                break;
            }
            OutFile.Write(&iRecLen2, sizeof(iRecLen));
            OldFortFile.Read(&iIn, sizeof(iIn));
            if (iIn != 0) {//this is the padding we need to ignore, ensure it's always zero
                    //Padding not found
                    break;
            }
        }
        OutFile.Close();
        OldFortFile.Close();
    }
    else { //Could not create the ouput file.
        OldFortFile.Close();
        return;
    }
}
else { //Could not open the input file

}
if (iError == 0)
    //File successfully converted
else
    //Encountered error
```

Comment: Note that this code doesn't support the subrecord scheme that gfortran uses to support records larger than 2 GB when using 32-bit record markers. Perhaps not an issue for you, or most people for that matter, but still..

Comment: Turns out this can be handled with a simple compiler option "-frecord-marker=8"